# FAQ Link Missing From Top of Page

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I remember before that the FAQ link was at the top of every Stack Exchange site.

I'm sure it use to be near your username in the top right corner.

[image: FAQ Link Missing]

Why has it been removed?

Can someone send me the link to the FAQ, please?

Comment: [Related announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that before posting this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) is no longer around, it's been replaced by the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help) that you see in the pic.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks for that.

Comment: What I find *really* irritating now is how inconsistent the top nav bar is across SE. For example in MSO when *not* logged in I see `log in  careers 2.0   chat  main  about  help`, but when logged in I see `username chat main about help`. So `chat main about help` is constant which is good. On SU for example though, when *not* logged in I see `sign up  log in`, and when logged in `username review chat meta help`. Where are chat/meta/about/help when not logged in, and where's about when logged in? On MSU the combination is again different.

Comment: IMO the **chat, main/meta, about and help** links are *absolutely essential* and should be present in the top nav bar on both main and meta of all SE sites in both logged in and out states, no exceptions. Scrolling all the way down for some of these is not acceptable (especially for new users), and the current approach is just a mess. I mentioned this previously [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center#comment559748_182812), but perhaps the devs will listen if the mods pass on the message?

Comment: @Karan MSO is a bad example for missing consistency, as it's a special case anyway. Comparing SU anon/me: You cannot chat when not logged in, so there's no point in showing it; about is a huge banner on the home page when not logged it as well as the new "tour" section (like "tags"); and FAQ/help is linked from the side bar when asking a question. No anonymous user cares about *badges*, so that was a waste of space. Anonymous users also get *month* (more interesting questions) instead of the regular home page. It's not *inconsistent*, but *tailored* to different audiences and information needs

Comment: @DanielBeck: Actually in this case MSO *is* consistent, but others aren't! You can't Chat when not logged in, but you can open chat and then log in there. The prominent link at least makes it obvious such an option is available. About/Tour are fine when on the front page but top nav links would help on other pages IMO. Badges was never a top nav link AFAIK, so I am not even including that in the discussion. I still feel **Chat, Main/Meta, About and Help** deserve to be *always* present to the left of **Search** for a consistent UI. There are lots of other locations where links can be tailored.

Comment: @Karan Badges wasn't in top bar, but among "questions/tags/users" just below (and much larger). I used it to illustrate the point that different home pages are both deliberate and useful for a majority of users. Showing "about" on top when it's both among those larger links and a huge banner would simply be redundant. Removing those banners again OTOH will just cause new users to not see it at all. Regarding chat, if you're not logged in, chances are you don't have an account, hence no way to chat. SE is pretty good in logging you in automatically if you have an account in my experience.

Comment: @DanielBeck: I have nothing against customised home pages or any other link sections for that matter. I still think the implementation of the top nav bar (which is the *only* area I've been focussing on from the beginning) at present across SE is haphazard and inconsistent. Guess we'll just have to agree to disagree on that. :)